# Plot data of a nest list

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have a nested list, such as, `{{{a1,b,c1}},{{a2,b,c2}},{{a3,b,c31},{a3,b,c32}},{{a4,b,c41},{a4,b,c42}},...{},...}`

The features of the list:

1. Some sublists have a single ordered triple of numbers, some have more than one triple, e.g. `{{a3,b,c31},{a3,b,c32}}`, and some are null;
2. The `{-2}` level is the level of the triples in their list
3. `b` is a fixed constant throughout the list, and `c_i`s are complex numbers.

I want to plot `a_i` versus the real part of `c_i`. Because some sublists have more than one triple of numbers and thus multiple `c_i` values, for the corresponding `a_i` there will be two points in the plot. Thank you!

Here is an example for testing

```
listTest = {{{0, 0.01, 0.9108613}}, {{0.01, 0.01, 
0.91076 - 0.00054857 I}}, {{0.02, 0.01, 
0.9104 - 0.0010988078 I}}, {{0.03, 0.01, 
0.9099769 - 0.0016523 I}}, {{0.04, 0.01, 
0.909291 - 0.00221086 I}}, {{0.05, 0.01, 
0.45553 - 10.081423 I}, {0.05, 0.01, 
0.9084125 - 0.0027759 I}}, {{0.06, 0.01, 
0.455581 - 8.40335 I}, {0.06, 0.01, 
0.907342 - 0.00334914 I}}, {{0.07, 0.01, 
0.455634 - 7.205064 I}, {0.07, 0.01, 
0.9060847446 - 0.00393201 I}}, {{0.08, 0.01, 
0.455695 - 6.306 I}, {0.08, 0.01, 0.904641 - 0.004526 I}}, {{0.09,
 0.01, 0.455762 - 5.6080917 I}, {0.09, 0.01, 
0.903 - 0.005132 I}}, {}, {}}
```

Comment: Why do you include empty lists? Will these be there in your real use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alist = listTest /. {a_, b_, c_} -> {a, Re[c]}
blist = Flatten[alist, 2] // Partition[#, 2] &
ListLinePlot[blist, Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Black , 
 PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image]